# Pandas dataframe transpose with column name instead of index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I can't seem to figure out how to show actual column name in json after dataframe has been transposed. Any thoughts please?

```
from pandasql import *
import pandas as pd

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q1 = """
SELECT
 beef as beef, veal as veal, pork as pork, lamb_and_mutton as lamb
FROM
 meat m
LIMIT 3;
"""

meat = load_meat()

df = pysqldf(q1)

#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#print(df.T.to_json(orient='records'))

df1 = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = range(len(df1.columns))
print(df.T.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Output

```
[{"0":751.0,"1":713.0,"2":741.0},{"0":85.0,"1":77.0,"2":90.0},{"0":1280.0,"1":1169.0,"2":1128.0},{"0":89.0,"1":72.0,"2":75.0}]
```

Expected Output

```
[ { "0": "beef", "1": 751, "2": 713, "3": 741},{"0": "veal", "1": 85, "2": 77, "3": 90 },{"0": "pork", "1": 1280, "2": 1169, "3": 1128},{ "0": "lamb", "1": 89, "2": 72, "3": 75    }]
```

Comment: What does df look like after pysqldf?

Comment: `[{"beef":751.0,"veal":85.0,"pork":1280.0,"lamb":89.0},{"beef":713.0,"veal":77.0,"pork":1169.0,"lamb":72.0},{"beef":741.0,"veal":90.0,"pork":1128.0,"lamb":75.0}]` each record as a dict without transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Where df:

```
   beef  veal  pork  lamb
0     0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6     7
2     8     9    10    11
```

Use `T`, `reset_index`, and `set_axis`:

```
df.T.reset_index()\
  .set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1, inplace=False)\
  .to_json(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
'[{"0":"beef","1":0,"2":4,"3":8},{"0":"veal","1":1,"2":5,"3":9},{"0":"pork","1":2,"2":6,"3":10},{"0":"lamb","1":3,"2":7,"3":11}]'
```

Comment: Thank you, works as expected. This is very helpful.

Comment: If I change the LIMIT to 5 rows, I get an error **ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 4 elements** any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a new question with sample bad data and error generated?

Comment: asked question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049101/pandas-dataframe-transpose-with-column-name-instead-of-index-throws-valueerror]