# Pandas dataframe transpose with column name instead of index throws ValueError

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, pandasql

I am trying to show actual column name in json after dataframe has been transposed, below code works for LIMIT 3 in sql but fails if I try LIMIT 5 Any thoughts please?

```
from pandasql import *

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q1 = """
SELECT
 beef as beef, veal as veal, pork as pork, lamb_and_mutton as lamb
FROM
 meat m
LIMIT 5;
"""

meat = load_meat()

df = pysqldf(q1)
#print(df.to_json(orient='records'))

hdf = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(hdf.T.reset_index().set_axis(range(len(hdf.columns)), axis=1, inplace=False).to_json(orient='records'))
```

ERROR

```
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `T` and `reset_index` , you have add one more `columns` , at the same time,  the length of `index` is equal to `columns` before transposed, so you should using `shape`

```
print(hdf.T.reset_index().set_axis(range(hdf.shape[0]+1), axis=1, inplace=False).to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This helped

Comment: @dcu yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.T.reset_index()\
   .set_axis(range(len(df)+1), axis=1, inplace=False)\
   .to_json(orient='records')
```

*Note: The issue is renaming the columns after the transpose, you need the length to be the number of rows in the original dataframe plus 1 for index.*

Output:

```
'[{"0":"beef","1":0,"2":4,"3":8,"4":12,"5":16},{"0":"veal","1":1,"2":5,"3":9,"4":13,"5":17},{"0":"pork","1":2,"2":6,"3":10,"4":14,"5":18},{"0":"lamb","1":3,"2":7,"3":11,"4":15,"5":29}]'
```